# How to delete hard copy of the image in the directory using CakePHP3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The code below is already working with manual deletion, I want to fetch the exact image , just like below

$file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/websites/image-todelete.jpg', false, 0777);

```
public function delete($id = null)
    {

    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $website = $this->Websites->get($id);      

    if ($this->Websites->delete($website)) {  
      $file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/websites/image-todelete.jpg', false, 0777);
          if($file->delete()) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The website has been deleted.'));
           }

    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The website could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

How to make this code

```
$file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/websites/image-todelete.jpg', false, 0777);
```

a universal code? 
If I ever delete data it should automatically delete the image in the directory when the record is deleted.

Comment: I think unlink() can do this.

Comment: @unlink() is the function

Comment: i want to code above using by id so that, img/websites/image-todelete.jpg to be a variable

Comment: Do your table has field to save filename like "image-todelete.jpg"..

Comment: yes i already had a table field name  "image" then after saving i save in the img/websites directory,  my problem is how to delete the image i added if that record is deleted.... this code  $file = new File(WWW_ROOT . 'img/websites/image-todelete.jpg', false, 0777); can delete already but I want universal, not just put the filename of the image, but the rows of the image if ever the record deleted, image will also deleted

Comment: @distromob how you name the files?

Comment: @AmanRawat  i save the data using this  $image_name        = $this->request->data['image']['name'];
   $image_tmp         = $this->request->data['image']['tmp_name'];
   $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'websites'.DS.$image_name;
   move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $destination);
   $this->request->data['image'] = $image_name;
   
$website = $this->Websites->patchEntity($website, $this->request->data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
public function delete($id = null)
{

$this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
$website = $this->Websites->get($id);      

// take destination just before deleting that
$destination= $website->destination;
if ($this->Websites->delete($website)) {  
  $file = new File($destination);
      if($file->delete()) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The website has been deleted.'));
       }

} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('The website could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
   }
   return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

And your saving method:

```
public function add(){
 $website = $this->Websites->newEntity();

 if ($this->request->is('post')) {


        //$image_name        = uniqid().$this->request->data['image']['name'];
        $image_name        = $this->request->data['image']['name'];
        $image_tmp         = $this->request->data['image']['tmp_name'];
        $destination       = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'websites'.DS.$image_name;
        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, $destination);
        $this->request->data['image'] = $image_name;
        $this->request->data['destination'] = $destination;

        $website = $this->Websites->patchEntity($website, $this->request->data);

        if ($this->Websites->save($website)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Data has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__(' Please, try again.'));
        }
    }



  $this->set(compact('website'));
  $this->set('_serialize', ['website']);
}
```

Do not forget to add field 'destination' field in the table..

Comment: it will return this when i debug  public_html/webroot/img/websites/Resource id #179'

but the record already deleted and the image still in the directory  @Manohar Khadka

Comment: /src/Controller/WebsitesController.php (line 127)
resource              =   which is this one debug($filename);

Comment: So don't you have field to save name of the image ? Isn't there any field which save file 'image-todelete.jpg' in the table.

Comment: I save into image field in the database, please modify my code bro :) if that is not cakephp standard

,,,please see code below

https://gist.github.com/distromob/b882d403779518dd56348a7525edd99b

Comment: Your code looks all good..Can you post result of debug($website); just after $website = $this->Websites->get($id);

Comment: 'image' => resource,
 'domain' => 'xxxx.com',
 'company' => 'company',
 'id' => (int) 40,
 'creation_date' => '2017-02-23',
 'hosting_provider' => 'Hostgator',
 'expiration' => '2017-02-28',
 'owner' => 'Not Hosted',

Comment: I think image name is not saving correctly in table..you need to check that in the table when you upload file..

Comment: actually the value of the image field in the table for all the records is [BLOB - 13 B] not the filename

Comment: You need to have save filename in the table and in the file directory..that two looks different..right ?

Comment: how will i do that buddy? im newbie all my codes come from google :)

Comment: But your code looks all good..You are saving $this->request->data['image']['name']; in both table and directory..You might need to debug little more.

Comment: if  i debug($destination) it will  display the exact file name of image and the path? how can i delete it?

Comment: i forgot to mention above that i debug($destination) after adding the data,

Comment: how can i call variable within controller to to another method in that controller?

Comment: I am still not getting you properly..Can you upload all files including your database in github?

Comment: i would like that buddy ,, with file upload

Comment: :)  wow thank you so much buddy its a big help for me. Thank You so much

Comment: so is that working , Otherwise I was just going to upload it in GitHub..I have just edited little bit in answer.

Comment: it is working now buddy thank you so much for your patience and effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try unlink() function.

```
unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img/websites/image-todelete.jpg');
```